# EditText not accepting numbers

Tags: android

A client is testing an Android app I made for them and they are using a tablet. They say that they can't enter numbers in an EditText, but it seems to work on my phone. What could be a reason or this?

Here is the code for a particular EditText:

```
pWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordsignin);
        y = false;
        signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        pWord.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    y = true;
                    new RegisterDeviceAsynctask().execute();
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
```

and the XML:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/passwordsignin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailsignin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>
```

Edit: The issue ended when I ended the setOnKeyListener code. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Mind getting the exact tablet including Android API version?

Comment: it's an asus transformer pad; android version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

tell your client to use two types of text, for example: android:inputType=     "typeOne|typeTwo" ... change typeOne and Two and use Log to print real output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Could you give an example?

Comment: Change the type of field and put "number" for tests, only numbers first.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:
1. Your  android:inputType="textPassword" will not let anyone see what is being entered. Try changing the android:inputType="text" so you can see if the expected character is being entered. That will let you debug the issue. It is possible the user is mistyping.
2. Try logging the password or putting it into a Toast so the user can see what they typed.

The above suggestions are for the debug period only. For release you don't want to have those in place. Your users should probably change their password after the debug period (or before, to a temporary password, and then change it back to the real password).

Comment: @user3140562 - setOnKeyListener is for hardware keyboards. I would investigate what Stephan Branczyk suggests as you might be dealing with different hardware environments and/or manufacturer-specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

```
android:inputType="TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD"
```

This will ensure that an appropriate keyboard/input method is selected for it (this can be dependent on the actual hardware manufacturer).

If that doesn't work, ask that they separate the physical keyboard from the tablet, to make the software keyboard come up.

If that doesn't work, see if they don't have a third party custom keyboard installed. Not only we have different hardware manufacturers, but since people can install their own keyboards from Google Play, that's another possibility.

If that doesn't work, ask them to take a screenshot of the keyboard they're getting on it, anonymize the screenshot the best way you can, and then post it on here in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just change youe code a bit:

```
pWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordsignin);
        y = false;
        signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        pWord.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    y = true;
                    new RegisterDeviceAsynctask().execute();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

just use this code as your SetOnKeyListener

```
if (keycode==keyevent.keyback)
{
...
}
else
{
return false;
}
```